# вывести данные в виде эксель

Tags: php, excel

Всем привет, может у кого то остался парсер, который выводит информацию в excel файле?
у меня есть свой, но он выводит информацию в виде echo

Comment: И изменить свой парсер чтобы он писал в ексель вы не можете?

Comment: если честн впервые сталкиваюсь с этим

Comment: Гугол уже изобрели.